# Identifying the parts of this typedef struct in C?

Tags: c, syntax

Please help me identify the parts of this `typdef` and what each part does and how it can be used:

```
typedef struct my_struct
{
        int a;
        int b;
        int c;
} struct_int, *p_s;

struct_int struct_array[5];
```

What I think they are, pleae correct if wrong:

1. `typedef struct` is creating a new type.
2. `my_struct` is the name of this type but not used in the rest of the code.
3. `struct_int` is one instance of the type that we can use in the code.
4. `*p_s` is the pointer specifically to the one instance we created.
5. `struct_array` is an array of the instance we created. (This part confuses me since we already created an instance...)

Also, when creating the array of structs, why do we use `struct_int` instead of `my_struct`?

Comment: We generally like _helping_ people with homework; I'm afraid this is getting close to _doing_ your homework. Can you fill in what your _guesses_ are for the different portions?

Comment: @sarnold: nice resume.........

Comment: Much better, thanks! (And thanks! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `typedef struct` is creating a new type.

The `typedef` is defining `struct_int` and `p_s`, which are synonymous to `struct my_struct` and `struct my_struct*` respectively. The idea is to save you from having to type things out the long way and to improve readability (which isn't always the case).

> `my_struct` is the name of this type but not used in the rest of the code.

Because you would have to use `my_struct` as `struct my_struct`, but you've `typedef`'d `struct_int` to refer to that type and it's simpler.

> `struct_int` is one instance of the type that we can use in the code.

No, read the above. If you removed the `typedef`, then you *would* be creating two variables `struct_int` and `p_s`.

> `*p_s` is the pointer specifically to the one instance we created.

No, read the above.

> `struct_array` is an array of the instance we created. (This part confuses me since we already created an instance...)

`struct_array` is an array of type `struct_int`, therefore it's an array of type `struct my_struct`. No *instance* is created in the definition of your `struct`.

> Also, when creating the array of structs, why do we use `struct_int` instead of `my_struct` ?

Same as one of the questions above; you can use `struct my_struct` or `struct_int`, `struct_int` is shorter and it'd defeat the purpose of `typedef`ing `struct_int`.

Answer (score 4):

`struct my_struct` is a name of a type, `my_struct` is a tag name and not a type.

`typedef` does not create types in C, but creates alias names for existing types.

Answer (score 3):

Not quite! Here's what different part mean:

`struct my_struct`: Here you are creating a new data type which you will refer to as `struct my_struct` whenever you want to create a new instance of the object. For example you should say: `struct my_struct a;` and **not** `my_struct a;`

`typedef struct my_struct {} struct_int;`: Here you merely create an alias for `struct my_struct` and name it `struct_int`. From now on, you can say `struct_int a;` instead of `struct my_struct a;`

`typedef struct my_struct {} *p_s;` Here, you create a new alias for a data type that points to `struct my_struct`. You can use it like this: `p_s newStruct = malloc(sizeof(struct_int));`

Answer (score 2):

`my_struct` is the name of this type of structure. It can later be used to declare more structures of this type.

`struct_int` is the name of the alias created by typedef.

`*p_s` is a pointer to a structure of the `my_struct` (aka `struct_int`) type. It can point to a structure of this type.

`struct_array` is the name of an array of `my_struct`s. However, since it is declared with the alias `struct_int`, we should refer to it later as one.

Using the alias is a personal preference, really one or the other of `my_struct` or `struct_int` could be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumptions are partly correct. I'd like to go into 3. and 4.

If you removed the `typedef` and had this:

```
struct my_struct {
  // ...
} struct_int_v, *p_s_v;
```

Then you would have declared two *variables* `struct_int_v` and `p_s_v` with the types you expected (one being `struct my_struct` and the other `struct my_struct*`).

However, when introducing the **stroage specifier** `typedef` you are telling C not to create a variable but a type, while the declaration syntax is identical.

Thus, `struct_int` will be the *type* that the variable `struct_int_v` would have and `p_s` will be the type that the `struct_int_v` variable would have.

Note that storage specifiers like `typedef` (or `static` for that matter) apply to all *variables* (while other qualifiers like e.g. `const` or `volatile` apply to *types* in contrast) up to `;`.

Comment: "you are telling C not to create a variable but a type, while the declaration syntax is identical." - didn't know that, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You mostly answered your own question, so I'll address the two remaining points I see:

First, the name of the type that the `struct` definition creates is `struct my_struct`.  You could declare variables like

```
struct my_struct a;
struct my_struct b;
```

but you don't want to have to write `struct` all the time so you create an alias using `typedef`.  It might be a little clearer to define the structure and the aliases separately:

```
struct my_struct {
  int a, b, c;
};
typedef struct my_struct struct_int;
typedef struct my_struct *p_s;
```

This first defines a type called `struct my_struct`, then defines `struct_int` as an alias for the type `struct my_struct`, then defines `p_s` as an alias for the type `struct my_struct *`.  The code you wrote has all three of these things combined into one, but it means the same thing.

Second, the type alias `p_s` has nothing to do with the array `struct_array`.  The `*p_s` doesn't define an instance of the structure, because it's part of a `typedef`:  it defines a type alias instead.  But even if there were no `typedef`, and `p_s` were therefore an actual pointer variable, the array defined afterward is a separate and unrelated variable.

Comment: When using `typedef` to create convenience aliases for structure types, it's common to omit the structure name entirely:  `typedef struct { /* ... */ } my_struct_type;`.  No sense having two different names for the same thing.

Comment: You can also directly create instances of anonymous structures:  `struct { int a, b; } my_two_ints;`.  Since there's no `typedef`, this defines an actual variable.

Comment: interesting, that makes sense.